# Will a thread sleep if told to sleep for zero seconds?

Tags: c++, sleep

My question is simple. If I use `std::this_thread::sleep_for(0ms)`, will the thread sleep at all?

I know this seems like a silly question, but when I tell a thread to sleep for a very small amount (such as 10 microseconds), it often sleeps for at least 5-10 milliseconds. I know this is related to how operating systems schedule their processes. I just want to know how all of the corner cases work, as I have some code that may be slowing down due to sleeping for small, zero, or negative amounts of time.

EDIT 1: I have simplified the question to just be about sleeping for zero seconds.

EDIT 2: Many comments so far has been about how I shouldn't try to do this, but I both have a reason and I'm curious. In my code, I am not literally calling `std::this_thread::sleep_for(0ms)`, but instead, I am sleeping for a variable amount of time based on external conditions. When I compute the amount of time I need to sleep, the result can be positive, negative, or zero. I want to know if I am still sleeping for results less than or equal to zero.

Comment: the question here is would you need to do so? The only overhead that you will have is entering the function, but for definition it will only run for the amount of miliseconds that you specified.

Comment: Why are you sleeping at all? Most code I see that sleeps, shouldn't.

Comment: The real question here is why would even sleep for 0ms? or even worse for "negative amount of time"?

Comment: It is platform dependent. On some platforms, `sleep(0)` is a way to yield to operating system. On others, it is a no-op.

Comment: @DimChtz there are platforms where sleeping for 0 is a way to yield to operating system.

Comment: If you want to yield then just use [std::this_thread::yield](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/yield)

Comment: A sleep (which you usually shouldn't be doing) will sleep for *at least* the time specified, but *may* sleep longer.

Comment: @SergeyA or it may sleep longer than specified and actually cause a delay.

Comment: Yielding the CPU is a code smell same as sleeping. Both are unsophisticated ways of managing concurrency.

Comment: Without more information it's hard for me to say what's better; worker thread pools with task queues might offer a way to schedule future work without sending perfectly good threads to sleep.

Comment: I ask because I have code in which I need to time an operation in order to avoid doing it too quickly. I sleep for a variable amount of time. Because of this, it's not possible to know beforehand how long I will be sleeping, and the amount of time could be positive, zero, or negative.

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't use [`std::this_thread::sleep_until()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until) instead?

Comment: Why wouldn't your compiler be justified in simply optimizing out a zero-sleep?

Comment: @Deduplicator As far as I know, they do the same thing under the hood, so my question remains the same either way.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I don't know what you mean by "your compiler". I would think the standard library and/or operating systems should optimize it out, but I don't know if it does, which is why I'm asking this question.

Comment: I don't understand the reason why is this downvoted and was put on hold. The question is explicit and clear.

Comment: @Zereges I edited the question and removed a couple of other related questions I was curious about, like whether it was platform-dependent and the behavior of sleeping for 0.0 (float) seconds. Not sure how to appeal the hold, though.

Comment: @qhs190 That *is* the way to "appeal" the hold. And I gave the last vote for reopening.

Comment: For Windows, the default tick rate is 64hz, or 15.625 ms. A sleep() or any context switch to another thread could cause a delay to the next 64hz boundary. The tick rate can be changed, up to 1000hz or 1 ms, using [timeBeginPeriod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timeapi/nf-timeapi-timebeginperiod). The increased rate of context switch checks will somewhat increase overhead.

Comment: I would try to debug this and have a look at the assembler code.
Perhaps your compiler is smart enough to terminate this thing,because it's zero waiting time.
Perhaps this will be a delay in a realy small time (have a look at what- and how many assembler commands be made and recalculate it with your clock frequenzy). This would be your sleep time.

Comment: Negative sleep time is surely undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

The most common behavior that I've observed on typical platforms is that it acts like a voluntary yield operation. That is, it will do nothing unless there is another ready-to-run thread that is not currently scheduled, in which case it will yield to that thread.

There are no specific requirements on how the platform handles this case. Treating as a no-op would be perfectly reasonable. Treating it as the shortest sleep the platform could support would also be perfectly reasonable.